# How to Calc Small Base and Sides of Isosceles Trapazoid using Base, Height and Angles

Tags: geometry

I am trying to determine the small base length, and side lengths of an isosceles trapezoid from a big base of $24''$, height of $8''$ and angles a/b of $22.5^\circ$.

I have found all kinds of equations that need 3 sides, or the area, and I have neither.

Comment: Could you share what you have got ?

Comment: This is the best I can do to describe what I have aside from what I put in the question http://prntscr.com/9f7uzh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this picture

[image]

you know $b$ and $h$, and the angle, I'll call $\theta$.  You can, right off the bat, see that

$$\frac{b-a}{2} = c \cos \theta$$

Putting this into the formula

$$h = \sqrt{c^2 - \frac{1}{4} (b-a)^2} = c \sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta}$$

Solving for $c$ gives

$$c = \frac{h}{\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta}}$$

Now we just need the formula for $a$,

$$a = b - 2 c \cos \theta = b - 2 \frac{h \cos \theta }{\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta}}$$

Now you just substitute your values ($\theta  =\pi/8, b= 24, h = 8$), and you should have it

Comment: I think I had my angles reversed and I need 67.5, not 22.5.  I entered the formula for c into mathway, using both 22.5 and 67.5, and it does not seem right at all.  67.5 gives me 25.997, which is longer than my base b.

Comment: I had originally used 45 degrees, not 22.5 degrees, and it was a simple result, $a=8$.  But for 22.5 degrees, it doesn't work, $a$ comes out negative.  That's fine, it just tells you there is no isosceles trapezoid with those dimensions.  Using 67.5 degrees, I get $c=8.66$ and $a=17.37$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your trapacium is $ABCD$ where $AD = BC = c$ since it is an isosceles trapezoid. As a consequence, the $\angle DAB = \angle ABC$ and $\angle ADC = \angle BCD = \alpha$ as depicted in the image:

[image: Trapazoid-1]

Suppose $AB = a$ and $CD = b$. Since you know the length of base and height with the size of the one of the angle (sappose they are $h$, $b$, and $\alpha$, respectively), we can find the $a$ and $c$ without using a formula:

Considering the right triangle $AED$,
$$\sin \alpha = \frac{AE}{AD}= \frac{h}{c} \Rightarrow \ c =\frac{h}{\sin \alpha} \tag1$$
$$\tan \alpha = \frac{AE}{DE}= \frac{h}{\frac12 (b-a)} =\frac{2h}{(b-a)} \Rightarrow \ a = b - \frac{2h}{\tan \alpha} \tag2$$

Since you know $h$, $b$, and $\alpha$, you can calculate $c$ and $a$ using the equations $(1)$ and $(2)$, respectively.

Also, it is noteworthy that $DE = CF = \frac{h}{\tan \alpha}$. Note that all of these unknowns are found without using pre-derived equations.